# Forcing NDSolve not to store full solution, in order to save memory

Tags: numerical-integration, memory, caching

When using `NDSolve` to integrate a time-varying dynamical system (ie, an initial value problem), I often only care about the final value of the dependent variables at the end of integration. However, `NDSolve` returns interpolation functions, implying that it is storing all intermediate values of the dynamical variables in memory.

Is there a way to save memory by forcing `NDSolve` to only return the final values of the dependent variables?

Comment: I assumed by `using NIntegrate to integrate a time-varying dynamical system` you mean you did `NDSolve`, right? if not, then it would be better to post MWE.

Comment: You are right, my regrets---I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired from Nasser's answer:

It's possible to return only the last (or some other specific values) value from `NDSolve`.

Try

```
sol3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 5, y[0] == 1, y'[0] ==0},y[5], {x, 4.5, 5}]
ByteCount[sol3](*16*)
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to save memory by forcing NIntegrate to only return the
>   final values of the dependent variables?

One way could be to just give it the small end range of interest, this way the interpolation function will have much smaller size. You can still give initial conditions at say `x=0` but tell it to given solution starting at much larger `x` value, and it will still work. The `x_start` in `{x,x_start,x_end}` does not have to be the same as the initial value of `x`.

For example, instead of

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 5, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 5}]
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x]+Sin[x]*x==5,y[0]==1,y'[0]==0},y,{x,4.5,5}]
Plot[sol2[x],{x,4.5,5},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you compare `sol` and `sol2`, you'll see `sol2` has less data in it.

```
 ByteCount[sol]
 (*3984*)

 ByteCount[sol2]
  (*1936*)
```

Comment: It's possible to return only the last value of `NDSolve`: `sol3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 5, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y[5], {x, 4.5, 5}]` ! `ByteCount[sol3](*16*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That's a good point which would be worthy of its own answer, perhaps.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 6):

I feel some clarification is needed to the answers by @Nasser and @UlrichNeumann.  There's not really much difference in the memory used by either.  @UlrichNewmann's `sol3 = NDSolveValue[..., y[5],...]` seems basically to be syntactic sugar for `sol3 = NDSolveValue[..., y,...]; sol3 = sol3[5]`.  The main memory saving comes from @Nasser's `{x, 4.5, 5}`, instead of which `{x, 5, 5}` would give even more memory savings.

Examples:  I've extended the domain so that the differences would be more noticeable.

@UlrichNeumann's method:

```
Quit[]

$HistoryLength = 0;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*  65508912 -- baseline  *)

sol3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 1/1000, y[0] == 1, 
    y'[0] == 0}, y[200000], {x, 100000, 200000}];
ByteCount[sol3]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
  16
  235687584
*)

MemoryInUse[]
(*  82906632  *)

Quit[]
```

@Nasser's method.  Note that the max memory usage and the memory in use after `sol3 = sol3[200000]` are similar.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*  65508848 -- baseline  *)

sol3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 1/20, y[0] == 1, 
    y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 100000, 200000}];
ByteCount[sol3]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
  59626536
  238685400
*)

MemoryInUse[]
(*  142533152  *)

sol3 = sol3[200000];
ByteCount[sol3]
(*  16  *)

MemoryInUse[]
(*  82906320  *)
```

The equivalent of using `{x, 5, 5}` with @UlrichNeumann's method.  Note that the max memory used is just a little above the memory in use.

```
Quit[]

$HistoryLength = 0;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*  65508848 -- baseline  *)

sol3 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + Sin[x]*x == 1/20, y[0] == 1, 
    y'[0] == 0}, y[200000], {x, 200000, 200000}];
ByteCount[sol3]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
  16
  85011648
*)

MemoryInUse[]
(*  82640112  *)
```